# AWS Redshift - correlated query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

The below correlated query in redshift returns data at times and the result set is blank sometimes.. is there something wrong with this?

```
select * from (
    SELECT
        L1.ID AS ID,
        L1.DNZ_CHR_ID,
        L1.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
    FROM
        RSDW_STG_LBV.STG_EBS_OKC_K_LINES_B_CURR L1
    WHERE
        (LSE_ID = 1
        OR LSE_ID = 14
        OR LSE_ID = 19)
        AND L1.ID <= (
        SELECT
            MIN(L2.ID)
        FROM
            RSDW_STG_LBV.STG_EBS_OKC_K_LINES_B_CURR L2
        WHERE 
        (LSE_ID = 1
            OR LSE_ID = 14
            OR LSE_ID = 19) AND 
            L1.DNZ_CHR_ID = L2.DNZ_CHR_ID
            )) a where  DNZ_CHR_ID=693729
```

I have translated the below oracle correlated query into redshift query.. and here goes the original one and works perfectly fine on oracle.

```
select * from (
    SELECT
        L1.ID AS ID,
        L1.DNZ_CHR_ID,
        L1.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
    FROM
        LINES_B L1
    WHERE
        (LSE_ID = 1
        OR LSE_ID = 14
        OR LSE_ID = 19)
        AND L1.ID <= ALL (
        SELECT
            L2.ID
        FROM
            LINES_B L2
        WHERE 
        (LSE_ID = 1
            OR LSE_ID = 14
            OR LSE_ID = 19) AND 
            L1.DNZ_CHR_ID = L2.DNZ_CHR_ID
            )) a where  DNZ_CHR_ID=693729
```

Comment: There are probably better ways to write this logic without a correlated subquery.  I would advise you to ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query should be doing.  As for your current issue, the most likely solution is that the data is different in the two databases, so the results are different.

Comment: The data is same across both the databases.. one is the source and the other is the staging area and external table on top of S3.

Comment: Check out the caveats. Your use case might not be supported https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html